# Create an extension method derived from ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, dictionary, extension-methods

I want to create an extension method derived from `ToDictionary()`. Currently to reach the desired result, I do this:

```
ObjectAttributes = model.ObjectAttributes.ToDictionary(
    oa => oa.Attribute.Name, oa => oa.ToWrapper<ObjectAttributeWrapper>());
```

So I use the following `ToDictionary` signature:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector);
```

I wish to know if it is possible to do this?

```
ObjectAttributes = model.ObjectAttributes.ToDictionaryWrapper<ObjectAttributeWrapper>(
    oa => oa.Attribute.Name);
```

here is the current implementation but it does not work obviously:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TWrapper> ToDictionaryWrapper<TWrapper, TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) where TSource : BaseModel where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper
{
        return source.ToDictionary(keySelector, model => model.ToWrapper<TWrapper>());
}
```

EDIT :
Implementation of `ToWrapper()`:

```
public static TWrapper ToWrapper<TWrapper>(this BaseModel model) where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper
    {
        if (model == null)
            return default;

        var type = typeof(TWrapper);

        if (_wrapperParents.ContainsKey(type) && _wrapperParents[type].Id == model.Id)
            return (TWrapper)_wrapperParents[type];
        else
            return (TWrapper)GetConstructor<TWrapper>().Invoke(new object[] { model });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TWrapper> ToListWrapper<TWrapper>(this IEnumerable models) where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper
    {
        var _models = models as IEnumerable<BaseModel>;
        if (_models == null)
            return default;

        return _models.Select(model => model.ToWrapper<TWrapper>());
    }
```

Comment: can you also provide us your current extension method implementation?

Comment: It depends on whether your extension method is going to need any extra generic type parameters on it

Comment: I do not think so.  A dictionary item is a KeyValuePair<object,object>.  There is no overload that take only one parameter.

Comment: @BarışAkkurt I added the current implementation

Comment: @canton7 There will only be one type "Wrapper" allowed

Comment: Are you trying to get a partially provided generic parameter list to work because you decided, that the compiler should be able to resolve the remaining parameters automatically?

Comment: @grek40 more or less yes ...

Comment: Do you have control over the `ToWrapper` method? Can you edit it/add a new overload?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, it's an extension method that I created. An idea of ​​a solution?

Comment: Can you show how it’s implemented? There might be a (not quite good) workaround depending on its implementation.

Comment: @Sweeper it's added ;)

Comment: You cannot specify partial generic arguments. You either have to specify none and let the type inference take care of it (if that’s possible), or specify all explicitly. Since you want to specify the `TWrapper` type, you would have to specify them all.

Comment: Do you really need a full generic key selector or is the key a property within `BaseModel`?

Comment: @grek40 it's always a BaseModel derived property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, for a single list of generic constraints, you can only provide all arguments explicitely or have all arguments resolved automatically. You can't have partially provided constraints.

So your options are the following (I assume `TWrapper` would have a property `WrappedObject`):

- Provide all parameters as is
- Reduce the number of generic parameters (you can even make the key type non-generic if its always the same)

```cs
// signature
Dictionary<TKey, TWrapper> ToDictionaryWrapper<TWrapper, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<BaseModel> source,
    Func<BaseModel, TKey> keySelector)
    where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper;
// call
model.ObjectAttributes
    .ToDictionaryWrapper<ObjectAttributeWrapper, string>(oa => oa.Attribute.Name);
```

- Split your function calls in two parts, where one part is explicit and the other implicit

```cs
// signature
IEnumerable<TWrapper> Wrap<TWrapper>(this IEnumerable<BaseModel> source)
    where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper;

Dictionary<TKey, TWrapper> ToDictionaryWrapper<TWrapper, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TWrapper> source,
    Func<BaseModel, TKey> keySelector)
    where TWrapper : IBaseWrapper;
// call
model.ObjectAttributes
    .Wrap<ObjectAttributeWrapper>()
    .ToDictionaryWrapper(oa => oa.Attribute.Name);
```

- Don't bother with the custom `ToDictionaryWrapper`, just use the Wrap-Function and the Framework `ToDictionary`

```cs
// call (signature for Wrap same as above)
model.ObjectAttributes
    .Wrap<ObjectAttributeWrapper>()
    .ToDictionary(w => w.WrappedObject.Attribute.Name);
```

Comment: I will test your solution! Thank you so much ;)